# CSS - yet another transition not working question

Tags: css, transition

Trying to understand `transition` css property, but can't seem to figure out why this code is not working. Border needs to go from `solid` to `dotted`

```css
.home {
  color: #ff652f;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 18px solid #ff652f;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom 3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-bottom 3s ease-in-out;
}

.home {
  border-bottom: 18px dashed #ff652f;
}
```

Made a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/h7925b8g/

Would like the transition to happen slowly. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Border needs to go from `solid` to `dotted`.

Comment: Transition can only animate continuous variables. `solid` to `dotted` is discrete transform. You can get a the desired effect using linear gradients and javascript. There's probably a css library that has this effect too.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you @GraemeNiedermayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `border-style` is not animatable, so you can't simply use the `transition` property to change it.

Instead, you can fake it. How exactly you pull this off depends on what you want the transition to look like. One approach is to use a repeating `linear-gradient` for the dashed effect and then transition that to overlay the border (either a literal `border` or just some other element that acts like a border).

For example, sliding up from the bottom:

```css
.home {
  color: #ff652f;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.home::before,
.home::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.home::before {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 0;
}

.home::after {
  height: 0px;
  transition: height 350ms ease;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 0px 10px, orange 10px 20px, white 20px);
  background-size: 20px 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home:hover::after {
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">Hover me!</div>
```

Or sliding in from the left:

```css
.home {
  color: #ff652f;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.border-animation {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: orange;
}

.border-animation::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 0px 10px, orange 10px 20px, white 20px);
  background-size: 20px 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 350ms ease;
}

.home:hover .border-animation::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="home">Hover me!<span class="border-animation"></span></div>
```